# The import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, pom.xml, hateoas

Hi I am new to spring boot and was trying to make a simple spring boot project with REST services.
I was trying to import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*; and use linkTo method but it is giving me an error that it cannot be resolved.
Here is my pom.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also here is my controller file-

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resources;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeRepository repository;
    EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository){
        this.repository=repository;
    }
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    java.util.List<Employee> all(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    Employee newEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return repository.save(employee);
    }
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {

          Employee employee = repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));

          return new Resource<>(employee,
            linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
            linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees"));
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
      Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
          .map(employee -> {
            employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
            employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
            return repository.save(employee);
          })
          .orElseGet(() -> {
            newEmployee.setId(id);
            return repository.save(newEmployee);
          });
      } 
    
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Some classes' names have been changed, and some packages have been move to another location. If you want to know more information, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes.representation-models .

Answer (score 1):

Try:

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
Or just .*

Comment: He OP does not have the same static import, the Bubbleshadow response is correct and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, replacing to `org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilderFactory`  from `org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;`  resolved the issue for this specific error.

They have provided the script which can modify your project to resolve your issue. However, I'll add that it did not work out of the box for my project and had to manually look through to find replacements. Below I've tried to put a table of what needs to be replaced with as I expect someone who will resolve this error to run into more errors due to migration of hateoas. If anyone finds any corrections in table, feel free to update answer:-

Script URL: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/main/etc/migrate-to-1.0.sh

| Original String | Replaced With |
| --- | --- |
| Link.REL_SELF | IanaLinkRelations.SELF |
| Link.REL_PREV | IanaLinkRelations.PREV |
| Link.REL_NEXT | IanaLinkRelations.NEXT |
| hateoas.EntityLinks | hateoas.server.EntityLinks |
| hateoas.ExposesResourceFor | hateoas.server.ExposesResourceFor |
| hateoas.JsonPathLinkDiscoverer | hateoas.client.JsonPathLinkDiscoverer |
| hateoas.LinkBuilder | hateoas.server.LinkBuilder |
| hateoas.LinkDiscoverer | hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer |
| hateoas.LinkDiscoverers | hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverers |
| hateoas.MethodLinkBuilderFactory | hateoas.server.MethodLinkBuilderFactory |
| hateoas.RelProvider | hateoas.server.LinkRelationProvider |
| hateoas.ResourceAssembler | hateoas.server.ResourceAssembler |
| hateoas.ResourceProcessor | hateoas.server.ResourceProcessor |
| hateoas.VndErrors | hateoas.mediatype.vnderrors.VndErrors |
| hateoas.VndErrors.VndError | hateoas.mediatype.vnderrors.VndErrors.VndError |
| hateoas.alps | hateoas.mediatype.alps |
| hateoas.core.AbstractEntityLinks | hateoas.server.core.AbstractEntityLinks |
| hateoas.core.AnnotationAttribute | hateoas.server.core.AnnotationAttribute |
| hateoas.core.AnnotationMappingDiscoverer | hateoas.server.core.AnnotationMappingDiscoverer |
| hateoas.core.DefaultRelProvider | hateoas.server.core.DefaultLinkRelationProvider |
| hateoas.core.EmbeddedWrapper | hateoas.server.core.EmbeddedWrapper |
| hateoas.core.EvoInflectorRelProvider | hateoas.server.core.EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider |
| hateoas.core.JsonPathLinkDiscoverer | hateoas.client.JsonPathLinkDiscoverer |
| hateoas.core.LinkBuilderSupport | hateoas.server.core.LinkBuilderSupport |
| hateoas.core.MethodParameters | hateoas.server.core.MethodParameters |
| hateoas.core.Relation | hateoas.server.core.Relation |
| hateoas.hal | hateoas.mediatype.hal |
| HAL_JSON_UTF8 | HAL_JSON |
| hateoas.mvc.BasicLinkBuilder | hateoas.server.mvc.BasicLinkBuilder |
| hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder | hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder |
| hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory | hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilderFactory |
| hateoas.mvc.HeaderLinksResponseEntity | hateoas.server.core.HeaderLinksResponseEntity |
| hateoas.mvc.ResourceAssemblerSupport | hateoas.server.mvc.RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport |
| hateoas.mvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker | hateoas.server.mvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker |
| hateoas.mvc.ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter | hateoas.server.mvc.ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter |
| hateoas.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter | hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter |
| hateoas.mvc.UriComponentsContributor | hateoas.server.mvc.UriComponentsContributor |
| ControllerLinkBuilderFactory | WebMvcLinkBuilderFactory |
| ControllerLinkBuilder | WebMvcLinkBuilder |
| ResourceProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter | RepresentationModelProcessorInvokingHandlerAdapter |
| ResourceProcessorInvoker | RepresentationModelProcessorInvoker |
| ResourceProcessor | RepresentationModelProcessor |
| ResourceAssembler | RepresentationModelAssembler |
| .ResourceAssembler | .RepresentationModelAssembler |
| ResourceAssembler | RepresentationModelAssembler |
| IdentifiableResourceAssemblerSupport | IdentifiableRepresentationModelAssemblerSupport |
| toResource( | toModel( |
| toResources( | toCollectionModel( |
| ResourceSupport | RepresentationModel |
| PagedResources | PagedModel |
| Resources | CollectionModel |
| Resource | EntityModel |
| RelProvider | LinkRelationProvider |